# filter in IE8 doesn't work, fix rgba in IE8

Tags: html, css, filter, internet-explorer-8, rgba

I need to do background-color with rgba(alpha) in IE8, but my code didn't work 
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: fixed; 
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);
}
.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As IE8 does support `rgb()` as a background colour the result is a solid coloured box.

Therefore we need to set the background back to transparent after the rgb rule (just in IE8 and below). After more Googling the answer was the [backslash 9 hack](http://webdood.com/?p=57).

```
#div{
    background:rgb(255,0,0);
    background: transparent\9;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4cFF0000,endColorstr=#4cFF0000);
    zoom: 1;
}
#div:nth-child(n) {
    filter: none;
}
```

For more, follow the tutorial http://rland.me.uk/cross-browser-alpha-transparent-background-10-2011

Comment: for me it's doesn't work div without any background color